# Run two daemon jobs in two different directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want to write a bash script that would start two daemon jobs in two different directories. This script should run in the foreground, and then when I press ctrl-c, the script would exit and bring down the two daemons with it.

Say the two daemons are two executables called `daemon1` and `daemon2`, and the two directories in which they need to start respectively are `dir1` and `dir2`.

How would I write such a script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "&" operator to run sub processes in the background, retrieve their PID (process ID) in the father process, and "wait" on both of them. Upon Ctrl-C bash will interrupt the "wait" and will quit the two sub processes.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Documents
ping localhost &
pid1=$!

cd ~/Downloads
ping localhost &
pid2=$!

wait $pid1 $pid2
```